# How to combine two button for an event using react

Tags: react-redux

The first click event of following code is same,i want to known wwhich method could use to combine them and make my code more concise.

```
<Button onClick={()={this.setState({disable:true});increasePostsVote(post);}}
><i className="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-lg"/> </Button>
<Button onClick={()={this.setState({disable:true});decreasePostsVote(post);}}
><i className="fa fa- thumbs-o-down fa-lg"/> </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're sharing A) most of the component markup, and B) the 'set state disabled on click' logic.

You could abstract a `FaButton` component and a `disable()` function to make things prettier:

```
function FaButton({ faIconClass, onClick }) {
  return (
    <Button onClick={onClick}>
      <i className={`fa ${faIconClass} fa-lg`} />
    </Button>
  );
}

const disable = () => setState({ disable: true });

   // Now your code 
   <FaButton faIconClass="fa-thumbs-o-up" onClick={() => disable(); increasePostsVote(post);} />
   <FaButton faIconClass="fa-thumbs-o-down" onClick={() => disable(); increasePostsVote(post);} />
```

Factoring out `FaButton` abstracts away much of the presentation logic, and the business logic is handled in onClick. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much.That's great.